# Extraction of characters of particular length from a given string in python Regex

Tags: python, regex

Hi I have records like,

Eg:

```
Health Insurance PortabilityNEG Ratio
Health Insurance PortabilityNEGRatio
Health Insurance PortabilityNEG NEGRatio
```

Here I need to extract `PortabilityNEG` 
I used the regex as

```
Insurance(.{25}).*?
```

But i don't want to mention Insurance.Kindly let me know how can I write the regex according to that?

Comment: `import re; re.sub(r"(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w{0,14})([\w ]+)","\\3","Health Insurance PortabilityNEGRatio")`?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can extract all the PortabilityNEG terms from the lines that you have given.

```
import re

a="""
Health Insurance PortabilityNEG Ratio
Health Insurance PortabilityNEGRatio
Health Insurance PortabilityNEG NEGRatio
"""
print re.findall('Insurance\s+(PortabilityNEG)',a,re.MULTILINE)
```

Output:

```
['PortabilityNEG', 'PortabilityNEG', 'PortabilityNEG']
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not want to mention "Insurance", you can try the following:

```
# Set up your test string
test_string = """Health Insurance PortabilityNEG Ratio
Health Insurance PortabilityNEGRatio
Health Insurance PortabilityNEG NEGRatio"""

# Set your pattern using regular expression groups
pattern = re.compile("(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w{0,14})([\w ]+)")

# Use re.sub to replace all groups with only the third group
[pattern.sub('\\3',x) for x in test_string.split("\n")]

# ['PortabilityNEG', 'PortabilityNEG', 'PortabilityNEG']
```

I hope this helps.